# conditional group by with enum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some trouble with a `DATABASE DESIGN.` Given is the following table:

```
group_id | right_id | mode
----------------------------
   1     |    1     | edit
----------------------------
   1     |    2     | edit
----------------------------
   3     |    1     | read
----------------------------
   3     |    3     | read
----------------------------
   1     |    3     | edit
----------------------------
   4     |    3     | denied
----------------------------
```

now I need for example all rights from group 1 and 3.
to prevent double results I want to group the results by the right_id
The problem is the mode column. As you may suggest the mode determines whether you are allowed to read or edit something (or nothing 'denied')

I want that highest privilege is used in the final result
a result for the rights of group 1 and 3 should look like this:

```
 right_id | mode
----------------------------
   1     | edit
----------------------------
   2     | edit
----------------------------
   3     | edit
----------------------------
```

the read mode from group 3 must be overwritten.

I have absolutly no idea how to solve this. I could make this in php but i want this in one query if possible.

Without a conditonal group by it seems totaly random which mode is choosen.

besides mode is an enum with the values

```
'denied', 'read', 'edit'
```

P.S.

I have read nearly every suggested link above but none of them are helpful :(

Thanks so far! :)

Comment: What's the name of the enum?

Comment: name of enum? sorry i don't know what you mean. The mode column is an enum field.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you meant by "besides mode is an enum with the values..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
select right_id,
       case max(mode+0)
            when 1 then 'denied' 
            when 2 then 'read'
            when 3 then 'edit'
        end highest_privilege
from mytable
where group_id in (1,3)
group by right_id
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/628fc/6).

Comment: damnit! When you see it! *g Totally works. Cant accept yor answer this fast, but i will for sure! It all seems a bit complicated, first change the string into a int and back to a strng, maybe i have to think again over the designe.... but thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @mercsen: I've updated my answer with a slightly simpler query (that relies on the ENUM order of mode.)

Comment: yup seems a bit cleaner. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use MIN/MAX functions in order to get what you want, since enum values have indexes:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

However you cannot use them directly, since MIN/MAX seem to work on enums as text values:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=45300

As you could see in one of  comments in above article you can use, f.ex: MAX(mode+0) and get index of enum value in return.

```
SELECT right_id, MAX(mode+0) AS mode FROM table WHERE group_id IN (1, 3) GROUP BY right_id
```

Which should give you in your case:

```
right_id | mode
----------------
1     | 3
----------------
2     | 3
----------------
3     | 3
----------------
```

Comment: Ahh thanks for this additional input, this clears some questions WHY it works. unfortunately i can only accept one answer and Mark Bannister was the first. But i really appreciate this! :) also i upvoted it, really useful

Comment: No problem here! I was just a tiny bit too late ;)